# jsPlumb doesn't repaint connections after browser back button

Tags: jsplumb

I dynamically create DIVs and connections. I scroll down page, then redirect (a href) on the 2nd page. Using back button on browser I came back to that paged and the connections are messed. They are rendered on the absolute position on the place, where the elements exists if page is not scrolled down.

Back button returns to the page and scroll down to origin position. But connections stay on the top, repaintEverything doesnt work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce issue in jsfiddle?

Comment: I try [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gunko/zybjopoc/21/) , but jsFiddle after back button do not remember scrollbar position and I think its forced to rebuild page or something. Its not rendered from browser (cached).

Comment: Here is screenshot: 
open page, connection are OK,
scroll little down and press F5
connections are messed
[tinypic](http://oi58.tinypic.com/1zcfiw9.jpg)